# Scenarios from cucumber .feature file not running

Tags: junit, cucumber, cucumber-junit

I have hundreds of feature files, all under same folder structure,Most run fine (using Junit) but some of them just do not run. All I get in console output is:-

```
     Feature: Verify  Customer Registration/ Sign Up

    @Web @Regression @P-High 
  Scenario: Verify the available fields on the Sign Up page

    Given user launches the browser and navigates to "HOME" page

    When user clicks on SignIn link from global header

    And clicks on SignUp link from SignIn page

    Then Verify below Sub/Main Module of My Account


0 Scenarios ()
4 Steps (5 skipped)
0m0.000s
```

I'v made sure that all the steps have stepdefinitions glued to it.

```
package com.aso.qe.test.runner;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class) @CucumberOptions(

    features="src/test/resources/features/web",
    glue="com.aso.qe.test.stepdefinition.web",
    tags = "@P-High",      
) 
 public class WebTestRunner{     }
```

Every feature file with tag @P-High has same issue
while every other feature file without this tag runs just fine.

Comment: Just to confirm if the issue is with the tag name can you change the tag name to something like `@P1` and run in your local copy.

Comment: @supputuri, I tried your suggestion and first time it ran fine, from second time onward it's back to it's original faulty behavior.

Comment: hmm. Can you add a simple message step for one of those cases and check, by running multiple times, by this way you will get to know if there are any flags that are hindering the execution second time onwards.

Comment: @supputuri, adding message would help only if it goes any further than loading base URL. It almost run like a dry run with the exception of launching browser & laoding URL.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out Not to be a tag or code issue. Each one of those files not running had scenario details on next line instead of right in front of keyword scenario (see example).

Scenario:
Check Flight Status

Once I fixed above everything was smooth.